# Bernoulli like inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

When does it hold that for $x\in (-1, 0), n>2$, $(1+x)^n<1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$? I know that for $n=3$ it's always true as

$$(1+x)^3=1+3x+\frac{3(3-1)}{2}x^2+x^3<1+3x+\frac{3(3-1)}{2}x^2$$

as $x^3<0$ for $x\in (-1, 0)$.

**EDIT:** I think that I found a proof by induction: I already proved the case $n=3$. Now let us suppose that it's true for $n=k$. Then, as $(1+x)>0$, we have

$$(1+x)^{n+1}<(1+x)\left ( 1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2\right )$$
$$= 1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2+x+kx^2+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^3=1+(k+1)x+\frac{(k+1)k}{2}x^2+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^3$$
$$<1+(k+1)x+\frac{(k+1)k}{2}x^2$$

as $x^3<0$. So, we cloncuded the proof.

Now I ask if is there a proof without induction.

Answer (score 0):

*(Too long for a comment)*

Rewrite the inequality for $y\in(0,1)$

$$(1-y)^n<1-ny+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}y^2$$

while

$$(1-y)^n=1-ny+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}y^2+\sum_{k=3}^{n}{n\choose k}(-y)^{k}$$

So it is equivalent to prove

$$\sum_{k=3}^{n}{n\choose k}(-y)^{k}<0$$